# Struct pointers are overriding each other

Tags: c++

I have a function:

```
    void initGraph(node_t *node, const int orderedInputNodes[]) {
    int index;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < S * 2; i++) {
        if (orderedInputNodes[i] == node->number) {
            index = i % 2 == 0 ? i + 1 : i - 1;

            node_t newNode;
            newNode.number = orderedInputNodes[index];
            newNode.left = EMPTY;
            newNode.right = EMPTY;

            if (node->left == EMPTY) {
                node->left = &newNode;
            }
            else if (node->right == EMPTY) {
                node->right = &newNode;
            }
        }
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Everytime I find a corresponding number I create `newNode`, assign its value to it and pass it either to the left or to the right, however, when the code comes to the part when the right child is being assigned, the left child gets overwritten. How come is that? I thought by stating `node_t newNode;` a completely new node will be automatically created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought by stating node_t newNode; a completely new node will be automatically created.

Correct. The problem is that the new node can *replace* the old node. Consider:

```
 for (int j = 0; j < 1000; ++j)
 {
     int i;
     i = 3;
 }
```

You don't think after this loop runs, there's a thousand instances of `i` still sitting around, do you? Every time this bit of code runs, a new `i` is created. But every time this bit of code runs, the `i` from the previous iteration doesn't exist anymore because it goes out of scope.

You have:

```
    {
        node_t newNode; // newNode is created here
        newNode.number = orderedInputNodes[index];
        newNode.left = EMPTY;
        newNode.right = EMPTY;

        if (node->left == EMPTY) {
            node->left = &newNode; // you save a pointer to it here
        }
        else if (node->right == EMPTY) {
            node->right = &newNode;
        }
    }
          // but newNode doesn't exist anymore here
```

So you've saved a pointer to an object that no longer exists. It winds up pointing to whatever happens to be stored in that memory, likely the next `newNode` that is created on the next pass in the loop.

Don't store pointers to local objects.

**Update**: You say you're coding in C++. Why are you using raw pointers then? Do you really want to manually manage the lifetimes of objects? C++ has fantastic tools to make this easy like `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: Ok, understood. But how do create a completely new node_t and store it as a reference without the possibility of it being overriten in the next iteration? Do I have to hold it forever?

Comment: Since I don't know what language you're using, I can't tell you. This question is tagged both C and C++, so I can't tell what you should do. Also, the code isn't complete and I can't tell what types things are, so again, I can't give you those kinds of suggestions. Maybe use `malloc` or `new`, depending on what language you are using.

Comment: Wait, there's a difference? If I had known that I would have tagged it as only C++. I'm using C++ currently. I'll retag it.

Comment: @tomashauser There are huge differences -- they're two different languages. Probably read up on how to use `new` if you're using C++. If you're using C++, why aren't you doing things the C++ way? You're making things *much* harder on yourself. Have a look at `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: I'm using C++ just because I need a std::vector. I have no experience with other things in there.

Comment: @tomashauser You can write C code in C++, but it will cause you a lot of needless pain. In that case, use `malloc` and `free`.